# Network Subnets (CIDR)

Tags: javascript, сеть, ip, ip-address

Help pls,

Скажите пожалуйста как можно идентифицировать покрыт весь диапазон IP адресов:

Например у меня есть: `parentsSubnets = ['10.0.0.0/8', '192.168.3.0/2']` при добавлении ip-адресов мне нужно понять сколько IP categorized и сколько uncategorized

Буду рад если есть человек который может помочь!

Comment: А что такое ```IP categorized```?

Comment: из диапазон parents cколько ip address было добавлено и сколько осталось

Comment: при добавлении адресов куда ? в каком виде они хранятся и вообще хранятся ли, после того как их добавили ? Что если добавляемый адрес вообще не входит в указанные диапазоны ?

Comment: мы разрабатываем веб-интерфейс, IP хранятся как обычные адреса. При добавление я проверяю диапазон но Мне нужно знать сколько ip остался в этом диапазоне и сколько добавлен, а диапазона несколько как пример `['10.0.0.0/8', '192.168.3.0/2']`